# Update an event by dropping an external event

Tags: fullcalendar

fullcalendar 1.4.7 allow adding new events by dropping them onto the calendar from an external list of events.
I would like to update the title of an existing event by dropping another event from the same list. How i can do that.
I wrote this function (below) and i call it from the "bindSegHandlers" function of fullcalendar.js but it doesn't work, a new event is created.

```
 function droppableEvent(event, eventElement) {
  eventElement.droppable({
   accept: '.myevent',
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
   hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
   drop: function(ev, ui) {
    alert('call dropped');
   }
  });
 }
```

Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself: eventRender is the right place for that!

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(evt, element) {
      element.droppable({
        accept: '.myevent',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
          alert('call dropped'); 
        }
      });
    },
    ....
    ....
  });
```

it is not necessary to modify fullcalendar.js

Comment: there is no eventRender method in latest fullcalendar. How to update an event by dragging external event in the latest version of full calendar? Any help would be great. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a direct answer to your question but you can consider it as an alternative option. I have used another jQuery based calendar plugin named Calendario and its pretty easy to add events in it.

[Calendario](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/codrops/Calendario/)

[image: Sample Calendar We Created for a website]