# Fullcalendar - Drag and Drop icons on event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using full calendar plugin. This plugin has a feature that allows external events to be dragged and drop on the cell(for specific day). However, I am looking for a way to associate external icons(image) with the events in the cell using drag and drop feature. Here is the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/) to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/) that I have created. To be more specific, I am trying to associate documents with the users. The administrator should be able to drag a document and drop it on the user displayed on the calendar. Although I have managed to display the icons with the events but don't know how to drag and drop the icons on the events. It would really appreciable if someone helps to achieve this. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: @ganeshk can you take a look into this.

Comment: Here is what I found something similar to my question but I am not sure how to implement it in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833949/dropping-onto-an-event-as-opposed-to-the-calendar-how-to-identify-event

Comment: Another useful link I found out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366654/update-an-event-by-dropping-an-external-event?rq=1 I will post the final solution for my own post soon after the implementation.

Comment: Hey - sorry, tied up with work today! You seem to be on the right track here - eventRender is the place to go. Make the event droppable before render and handle the icon drop from there. Also note that if you mark the calendar as droppable, this approach might not work as the day element also will be droppable. All the best - let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found for my question [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/9/) Hope this will certainly help someone in need. Up-vote me if you find this solution helpful :)